# Configure Visual Studio 2010 web application project to run on localhost:8080

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, virtual-directory, vs-web-application-project

I am using local IIS instead of the VS Web Server but instead of a virtual directory on the Default Web Site, I want to configure my web application project to run in its own IIS Web Site on port 8080. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a website on IIS, using port 8080.

Point the home directory of this site to the web application project directory.

To debug on IIS, attach to the worker process (`w3wp.exe`).

Comment: setting up the Web Site in IIS first was the key. Normally with a virtual directory based web application, VS will create it for you. Apparently it won't create an IIS Web Site for you though if you change the web application project settings to use localhost:8080

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into your Web Application project properties. Under the tab "**Web**" you can select "**Use Local IIS Web server**" and create from this point a virtual directory for your app. The only part you have to configure on the iis side is the port number for your website.

Comment: this is what i typically do, but in this question i asked about how to do it using a separate IIS Web Site, not just a virtual directory in the Default Web Site

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your question, sorry.